# How to avoid Bottom View to come over the Keyboard in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard, scrollview

My View is something like this:

```
        VStack{
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<50) {_ in
                Text("Editor")
            }
            
      
            VStack {
                TextField("My Text Filed, text: $text)
            }
            .frame(minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 200)
            
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6.0)
                    .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1.0)
            )
            .padding()
        }
        
        Button("My Button")
            .background(.green)
            .padding()
    }
```

My problem is that whenever clicking on text field my Button comes on the top of keyboard. I know this is cool feature and expected that view out side if scroll will come to top of keyboard. I want to avoid this, can any body give some solution how to avoid this.

I want my Button to always be below the ScrollView in the bottom not on the top of keyboard

Comment: To keep the button always below the ScrollView and not on top of the keyboard is to use a **GeometryReader** to detect the keyboard height and adjust the position of the button accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
@State private var text = ""
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Button("Button title") {
                print("Button tapped!")
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<50) {_ in
                Text("Editor")
            }
            VStack {
                TextField("My Text Filed", text: $text)
            }
            .frame(minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 200)
            
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6.0)
                    .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1.0)
            )
            .padding()
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution I have already applies but there are some issues using ZStack. One is like, Done Button is overlapping to ScrollView in bottom. do you have any third process for the same

Comment: You can add padding bottom in scroll view as I did.

Comment: But for that we have to calculate the button Height. it could be a View as well and calculation can come with extra process cost

Comment: yes. are getting any other solution?

Comment: And padding will also apear on the top of keyboard @Jatin Bhuva

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me in `iOS 16`:

```
@State private var text = ""
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(0..<50) {_ in
            Text("Editor")
        }
        VStack {
            TextField("My Text Filed", text: $text)
        }
        .frame(minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 200)
        
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6.0)
                .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1.0)
        )
        .padding()
    }
    Button("Button title") {
       print("Button tapped!")
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
  }
}
```